# CutePDF auto save issue from PowerBuilder 11.5

Tags: windows, powerbuilder

We are using window 7, PowerBuilder 11.5 and CutePDF, In our application we have a functionality that prints report & saves auto matcially with a name. Some of our machines did not working and So we installed Converter after that some machines are functioning with this functionality and in some machines we are still facing the issue as that functionality unable to create PDF files. What will be the cause?and is there any procedure to install Cute PDF and Converter?
Please suggest and help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Same users? same permissions? same folder structure?

Comment: Yes, same users, permissions and folder structure

Answer (score 0):

If you can use other than CutePDF then I will suggest you below steps:

1. Download the Open Source GhostScript[Version: gs8.71]
   (If your Win7 is 64bit then download the 64-bit GhostScript)
2. Install GhostScript by running as Administrator and install for all users.
3. Once gs is installed then add a printer by using the gs driver.
4. Most Important: Name the printer as "Sybase Datawindow PS"

Now any Powerbuiler datawindow report can be simply print to PDF by just doing dw_1.SaveAs("FileName")